# How to use dynamic topology for terrain modeling

Tags: modeling, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I tried to get some hills and valley on a 2x2 Km plane with dynatopo, but it is invisible as it seems to be limited in the height it can produce. How can i get it to make bumps that are realistic for that use (100m big or even more) ?

**Notes:** I know the solution using subdivided planes and proportional editing but it is not as powerful and flexible.
As it as to fit the rest of the scene, I can't realistically work on a 2m plane and then scale to 2Km every time to check if it's ok and then back to 2m to polish, that back and forth is way to time consuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try applying scale to the object, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Scale.

There shouldn't be any limit to the height you can sculpt, but object scaling might make the sculpting influence too small. Also this is probably a general sculpt mode problem not specific to dynamic topology.

Comment: thanks, it works indeed. Setting the strength to 10 gives also really interesting effects, which were not there before applying scale :) (totally buggy but really nice)

Comment: If you created a plane of 2000 by 2000 blender units you are probably experiencing precision errors.

Comment: It was 2000meters, but I guess it's the same as I didn't use any factor in world tab, only switched to metric. But those precision error don't come with strength set to 1. Anyway, nice bug so don't remove it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not apply the scale of the object/mesh (ctrl+a select scale) before sculpting; brush strength will seem like its too light, thats why you only see effects when you set the strength to high numbers like 10.

you also need to set you your clipping distance to a higher number if your working with a 2x2 km plane. (Press n on the viewport to open properties shelf and on the to view section set clip end to a high number/depends on your scene units and scene scale)

dynatopo is meant for scketching the rough geometry and is not very suitable for full details.You can always create a basic topological skecth from dynatopo and then reproject it to a new plane with "shrinkwrap" modifier (be sure to select "project" from drop down menu inside the modifier)

after that you can go as high as 45 million polys on multires sculpting.(depends on the system) i can work with 63 million for example.